# How to find the value of selected item and also with that the not selected options value from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a dynamic array that consists of many objects. For example, the array is,

```
const dynamicArray=[{type:A, value:[1,2,3]}, {type:B, value:[4,5,6]}]
```

There might be so many objects. I mapped this array and returned radio buttons so that I can pick options. What I did is,

```
{
dynamicArray.map(item=>(
                      <>
                        <h1>{item.type}</h1>
                        <RadiaGroup>
                           {item.value.map(value => (
                             <Radio>{value}</Radio>))
                           }
                        </RadioGroup>
                      </>
                      )
}
```

I want to get the value by firing onSelect event on the radio button, and also want to get other selected values from selected radio buttons. like, if the user chose type A and clicks it, I want to have its value and also the other object Type B's value. Like, 1 from A, and 4 from B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to `onChange` event on the `RadioGroup`, and you need to pass the `item.type` as a parameter.

```
const dynamicArray=[{type:A, value:[1,2,3]}, {type:B, value:[4,5,6]}]
```

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState(dynamicArray.map(i => ({type: i.type, value: '' })))
 const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) => {
    setValue(prev => {
       prev[index].value = event.target.value
       return [...prev]
    })
  };
```

```
{
dynamicArray.map((item, index) =>(
   <>
     <h1>{item.type}</h1>
     <RadiaGroup onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)} value={value[index].value}>
       {item.value.map(value => (
         <Radio>{value}</Radio>))
       }
     </RadioGroup>
    </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Hello Mina, here when I click the first button, it returns the first radio button value, btw I need to have the other radio button's current selected value too with the onchange. is there any way?

Comment: @AnwarHossain, so you need to control it with a `state`, I just update the answer, please check again.

Comment: That's the answer I needed. Thanks.